# Background images on website appear blurry on iOS

Tags: ios, image

On iOS devices background images appear blurry. If someone can point out what I need to do that would be great. I'm also pretty new to this so please explain.

[image: Screenshot showing the background of the web site on a desktop. The background is sharp and clear.]

[image: Screenshot showing the background of the web site on iOS. The background is blurry and pixelated.]

```css
#home-cover {
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("../img/bg-home.jpg");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <!-- required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
    <meta name="description" content="Building modern responsive website with html5, css3, jQuery & bootstrap framework">
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML5, CSS3, jQuery, Bootstrap, Web Design, Web Development, Responsive website, Modern website">
    
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- title -->
    <title>Genesis Utility</title>
    
  
     <!-- Home -->
    <section id="home">

        <div id="home-cover" class="bg-parallax animated fadeIn">

            <div id="home-content-box">

                <div id="home-content-box-inner" class="text-center">

                    <div id="home-heading" class="animated zoomIn">
                      <h3>Genesis Utility <br> Communication Inc.</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div id="home-btn" class="animated zoomIn">
                        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-general btn-white smooth-scroll" href="#about" role="button" title="View Our Work">Learn About Us</a>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set a background size property.  Assuming based on your design, you want cover

```
#home-cover {
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("../img/bg-home.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I added your suggestion and it still isn't working on my IOS device. very blurry.